# Broke one letter key of my laptop's keyboard and want to remap it on the right Window's key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, hardware, remapping

Some days ago I accidentally spilled some soda on my laptop and broke one of the keys, specifically the letter 'v'. The computer isn't actually mine so I'm ordering another replacement to the keyboard which arri'v'es in 10 days.
Until the new keyboard gets installed I ha'v'e to make a little fix on my laptop to stop the pain of pasting the 'v' using a mouse. So I thought of remapping Right Windows (key I do not use) to temporally fix the problem.

**T.L.D.R. Need to remap the letter 'v' to the Right Window's key and don't know how.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try Key Mapper GUI...

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper

```
sudo apt install git python3-setuptools
git clone https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper.git
cd key-mapper && ./scripts/build.sh
sudo dpkg -i ./dist/key-mapper-0.6.0.deb
sudo apt -f install  # installs dependencies
```

Usage instructions are here...

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper/blob/main/readme/usage.md